# Node-Webkit gclient sync error

Tags: node-webkit

I want to build Node-Webkit. I followed the instructions from this site https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Building-node-webkit but the part with the .gclient file didn't work.

After the command `gclient sync --nohooks`, I get this:

```
ERROR: client not configured; see 'gclient config'
```

The solution I found for this problem was the gclient config http://... command with a link like https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src or similar ones.  But with these links gclient doesn't download the Node-Webkit stuff.

So is there a working link for this problem or a option to download the stuff without gclient?

I did it with a fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04 in a virtual machine because the install-build-deps.sh I have to execute later does not support my Ubuntu 13.10.

Could the vm be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set config to gclient, which generates .gclient in home folder. [Read more here](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Developers/Building%20NW.js/#get-the-code)